# How to use object-oriented design with Mongoose objects

Tags: oop, typescript, mongoose

I'm new to Javascript & Typescript, I'm used to doing objected-oriented design in Java where we put the behavior in the same class as the data when possible.  I'm not sure how to do this with mongoose.

As an example, this is some code that I found on my current project (simplified for this example) :

```
// get production object from mongo
const production = await ProductionModel
  .findOne({_id: id}).exec();

// update the data
if (this.isNumber(unsold)) {
  production.unsold = unsold;
}

// do some data checking
if (production.unsold < 0) {
  throw new Error('Unsold must be >= 0');
}
if (production.productions.length < production.unsold + production.mistakes) {
  throw new Error('INCOHERENCE_BETWEEN_PRODUCTION_AND_UNSOLD');
}

// save the production object
await production.save();
```

In Java I would use setters to validate the data so that this is done in one place (in the Production object) and re-usable by all.  Is this possible with Mongoose?  For example, I'd like to create a setter for mistakes.  Inside this method I'd verify it's > 0 and that the sum of mistakes + unsold is not less than productions.

I can define that but I have an interface and a schema, where does the setter go?  It seems I can't add it to the interface so I'd have to make that a class (why does everyone use interfaces with mongoose instead of classes?).  If I add it to the schema it will be available in the model, but in most of my code I try to avoid using the model and stick to my interface.  And now I'm confused. ;)

Is this even common in type typescript world?  I've searched about this but I haven't found a solution so I have the impression this is not how it's done in typescript.

Thanks

Comment: How about this: https://gist.github.com/masahirompp/3c012c8721b70821fa45 ? It uses a class (`User`) to wrap the document interface (`IUser`)

Comment: The comments in that post say it doesn't compile.  The idea is interesting but I'm really surprised people didn't get it to work and I'm even more surprised that there are not more answers to this question - which leads me to believe this is not something that is done in the JS/TS Mongoose world.  I find that disappointing.

Comment: It's doable, I've done it before. But the thing is that it's a very specific solution based on the model you have. There's no generic way. You basically need to have an interface per document which is used with mongoose and then a class to wrap it, then you only use the class.